# How does SQL Server calculate the Cost Threshold for Parallelism

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thank you in advance.

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database server serving web content.  The server has 2 dual core CPUs.  MDOP is set to 2, and the Cost Threshold is set to 5 (default).

We have a few queries that seem to peg our CPU when put under load.  We are seeing high values for CXPACKETS and SOS_Scheduler_Yield wait types.

How does SQL Server Calculate the expense of the query?  I would like to make sure we set the correct value for the Cost Threshold value.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: This question is more appropriate on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks.   I did find this article online after I posted.  Thanks.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/01/19/tuning-cost-threshold-of-parallelism-from-the-plan-cache.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what was found online.

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/tuning-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-from-the-plan-cache/